# Windows 7 VM taskbar disappears if I go up to a resolution > 800x600 Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution

The host OS is Ubuntu Gnome and my hypervisor is Oracle Virtual Box. I've made sure that my drivers are up to date on the VM, and I set the scale factor to 100%. Guest additions ISO has been checked in the menu. 800x600 is too small, but any larger screen resolution will cause my VM screen to expand too far vertically.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just as a point of clarification, you can't set the VM screen resolution to be the same as your desktop resolution (e.g. 1366x768)?

Comment: I'll have to check for it when I get back home to let you know. Thanks for a response!

Comment: Not a problem. =) And indeed, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have 1280 X 1024 running on my host OS, and that option is available in the Windows VM but it's too large. However, I'm happy with scaled mode. It's close enough to full screen and I really have no reason to run windows 7 except for nostalgic reasons :)

Comment: Indeed. Well, as long as it makes you happy (enough). =)